# Python how to add labels to plot in one liner

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label

I can't seem to find a simple one liner that includes everything I need for my plot. Looking for some guidance here -

I have a simple one line of code for a bar plot:

```
df[df.day=='Friday'].groupby('day').agg('amount').mean().plot(kind='bar',x='day',y='amount')
```

Which works well, but I'd like to add labels to the bar chart. So each bar shows the mean value for that day. Can I do this annotation within this one line?

Comment: No but you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart).

Comment: just seems like it should be easier

Comment: But it isn't unfortunately.

Comment: It's just two more lines of code, I don't think it's that complex. That said, I'd loop over the bars and extract the information them rather than loop over the plotted data.